# select records with one query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count

These are my tables structure :

data :

```
id   | name
-----+-------
1    | d1
2    | d2
3    | d3
```

supplier :

```
id   |  data_id    |  name
-----+-------------+----------
1    | 1           | Microsot
2    | 1           | Google
3    | 1           | Yahoo
4    | 2           | Apple
```

connector :

```
id   |  supplier_id   |  name
-----+----------------+-----------
1    | 2              | Test 1
2    | 1              | Test 2
3    | 4              | Test 3
```

Now I want select all columns of `data` records and `COUNT()` of records which are in `connector` table which the `data_id` in `supplier` table is equal with `id` of `data` table.

the result should be like this:

```
id    |   name    | COUNT()
------+-----------+---------
1     | d1        | 2
2     | d2        | 1
3     | d3        | 0
```

How can I do this with one query in mySQL ?

Comment: RTLM: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29

Comment: @GordonLinoff I trying with tow queries, I want to know is there any way to wrote in just one query ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
   data.id,
   data.name,
   COUNT(DISTINCT connector.id)
FROM
   data
   LEFT JOIN supplier ON (data.id = supplier.data_id)
   LEFT JOIN connector ON (supplier.id = connector.supplier_id)
GROUP BY
   data.id, data.name
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select data.id, data.name, count(*)
  from data 
  join supplier on supplier.data_id = data.id
  join connector on connector.supplier_id  = supplier.id
  group by data.id, data.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

`SELECT data.id, data.name, COUNT(data.id)
FROM data 
LEFT OUTER JOIN supplier ON(data.id == supplier.data_id)
LEFT OUTER JOIN JOIN connector ON (supplier.id == connector.supplier_id)`